# How to put digits of an integer in a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, integer, digits

If a user enters an integer like 4210 for example, how can I put each digit of that integer in a vector in C++?

Comment: Do you mean std::vector<int> iv{4,2,1,0}??

Comment: Yes, but I want the end user to enter these numbers not the programmer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261589/howto-split-a-int-into-its-single-numbers

Comment: Yes I know about push_back, but How can I loop on an integer to get each number in it? Is that allowable?

Comment: Simplest would be to input it as a string and then just iterate that string, pushing every element into a vector. After you have each digit separately it's trivial to lexically cast it to integer for vector<int>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done like:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int x;
std::cin >> x;
while(x>0)
{
   numbers.push_back(x%10);
   x/=10;
}

std::reverse(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

Comment: Well, I will try it. It doesn't matter - for my application - if the addition was in reverse order.

Comment: change it to a stack, or treat the vector like a stack..."reverse order" is relative to how you read it later.

Comment: use 'numbers.emplace(numbers.begin(), x%10);'  instead of 'push_back()' to avoid overhead of reversing the vector.

Comment: Using `emplace(begin())` does not improve performance, but instead makes performance worse, because each `emplace` at the beginning requires all previously added elements to be moved, giving the entire loop complexity O(n^2), whereas `std::reverse` has complexity O(1).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why people advise such round about solutions as converting back and forth to `int` when all you want is digit by digit... for a number expressed in decimal by the user.

To transform `"4321"` into `std::vector<int>{4, 3, 2, 1}` the easiest way would be:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

std::vector<int> vec;

for (char const c: input) {
    assert(c >= '0' and c <= '9' and "Non-digit character!");
    vec.push_back(c - '0');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Easiest way I found is this :

```
std::vector<int> res;

int c;
std::cin >> c;

while(c>0)

    {
    res.insert(res.begin(),c%10);
    c/=10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer using `std::string` you can use:

```
std::vector<int> intVector;

int x;
std::cin >> x;

for (const auto digit : std::to_string(x)) {
    intVector.push_back(digit - '0');
}
```

This assumes your compiler can use C++11.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d8be06f491fcc9)

Comment: My compiler is gcc on Ubuntu Linux, it is updated to version 4.8.1. I normally compile my simple programs with 'g++ -Wall -o'. How to compile on C++ if that wasn't it?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o, should work fine.

Comment: Those numbers represent the powers in an equation of the taps in a linear feedback shift register, I will use the numbers as addresses for bits to be xored in a bitset. So, I don't think that conversion into a string is correct if I want to do that, I just want them integers as they are. Thank you.