# How is an integer, in binary format, converted to a string containing it's decimal counterpart in depth?

Tags: c++, string, binary

I was attempting to write 128 bit integer class in C++ with the number being stored in binary format across two `int64_t`. As I was trying to write the function that converts my number into an `std::string` (so I can show it somewhere like in `cout`) I got stuck and it raised a broader question to which I couldn't find any answer.

Consider the number `16`, in memory that number is laid down that way: `00010000`, unless I'm wrong, any occurrence of `16` in decimal form (in the code, as output values, debugger values, etc.) is in fact a string that contains two characters of values `49 (ASCII code for '1') and 54 (ASCII code for '6')`

So how does the conversion from `00010000 (value in memory)` to `"16" (string)` happens ?

I understand that this question sounds a bit trivial, but in my case I can't fit the numbers I want in any existing container, it would be a bit like having a 32 bit integer in binary format but no `int` type, how would you print the number inside it ?

Comment: This other question collected a lot of example implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an integer to an array of its digits in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336605/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-an-array-of-its-digits-in-c)

Comment: Another related question: [Finding a Specific Digit of a Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410629/finding-a-specific-digit-of-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for conversion of non-negative numbers:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string uint_to_string(unsigned int value, int base = 10)
{
    if(base > 36 || base < 2)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Base must be between 2 and 36");
    if(value == 0)
        return "0";
    std::string digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    std::string result;
    while(value > 0)
    {
        int digit = value % base;
        char c = digits[digit];
        result = c + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```