# separate digits of a long number in c++

Tags: c++, long-integer, digits

I have for example the long number 12345678901 and I want to get separately each digit to use it. I tried really hard but I didn't make it so far? Any ideas?

but I have a problem in all of them
when I try those with a number of 11 digits and more (that what I want) my program stops working
I'm running my program in visual studio
in other case-smaller numbers--is just fine..
any connection with the fact that my number is long?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split an Integer into its digits c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207696/split-an-integer-into-its-digits-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you digits in variable `b`.

```
long a = 12345678901;
while(a > 0) {
   long b = a % 10;
   a /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<int> digits;

while(number > 0)
{
   digits.push_back(number%10); //push the last digit in
   number /= 10; //truncate the digit
}

std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end()); // the digits were in reverse order
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the number to a string (not sure what the method is for that but I know such things exist) and then access each character of the string one at a time.

Comment: YOu can do this with the itoa function

Comment: sprintf(myString, "%d", myNumber);

Comment: Yikes :) Why not just `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(myNumber)`? I think `lexical_cast` might be becoming part of the standard library in C++0x (I'd need to check), which makes that approach even easier.

Comment: lets say i use itoa that returns char*.how can i use the third digit for example?

Comment: how i use lexical cast?with that line you wrote sgolodetz?

Comment: @user501986: Well once you've stored the result of the `lexical_cast` in a string `s`, you'd just say `s[2]` to get the third digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
long residual= number;
int base= 10;

do
{
    long digit= residual%base;
    std::cout << digit << '\n';
    residual/= base;
} while (residual!=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the digits, you can get what you want by converting it into a string:

```
// This converts the binary representation of the long into a string.
std::stringstream ss;
ss << long_number;
std::string number_as_string = ss.str();

// Then visit all the characters of the string.
for (std::string::const_iterator it = number_as_string.begin();
     it != number_as_string.end();
     ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

This will print the numbers, say, if you have 12345:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So you can process each of them accessing the iterator `*it` as the above code.