# Given a n digit long integer, how to access its parts?

Tags: c++, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split an Integer into its digits c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207696/split-an-integer-into-its-digits-c)

Given a number `4567`.

In C++, how can you separately access `4`, `5`, `6` and `7`?

Comment: *Given a number `4567`*... how is the number *given*? Is it a string, is it an `int`?

Comment: Not just that; will you repeatedly need to access them? Do you need to treat negative numbers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones digit is `n % 10`, the tens digit is `(n / 10) % 10`, and so on.  Be careful about negative numbers, the rules are slightly different.

Comment: Thank you Keith. Nice and simple indeed

Answer (score 1):

Just to augment answers already here...  You do long division.  This gives you the least significant digits first.

```
n = abs(n);
while( n != 0 ) {
    int r = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    cout << r << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
7
6
5
4
```

Obviously, this method gives you the least-significant digits first.  You could of course generate that into an array so that you could access each number by its power (element 0 is 10^0, 1 is 10^1, etc...)

To go the other way, convert the number to a string.  This approach will be slightly less efficient than long division.  I know this question stated C++, but there's nothing wrong with using the C function `itoa`.

```
char s[33];
itoa(abs(n), s, 10);
for( char *d = s; d != 0; d++ ) {
    int r = *d - '0';
    cout << r << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about C++, but I know python at least will round always down, so to get the last digit you could use mod 10, and then divide out the last digit by 10, so, in sudo code

```
 int num_to_test = 1234;
 for (int i = 0; i < num_to_test.length; i++ ) {
      print num_to_test % 10;
      num_to_test = num_to_test / 10;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a little math and reduce the num as you go. Like this:

```
int thousands = floor(num / 1000);
num = num - thousands * 1000;

int hundreds = floor(num / 100);
num = num - hundreds * 100;
```

and furthermore, I hope you see where that is going.

Comment: You don't need to use floor since it is an integer. The floor function is used to round a double value down.