# Truncate an int value

Tags: c++

I want to make a function which takes an integer with the number like 113, and separates the one's digit "3" and and the hundreds and tens places "11"  and returns the both of them in two separate integers.

Comment: Look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207696/split-an-integer-into-its-digits-c

Answer (score 6):

`x%10` for the first digit (from right) and `x/10` for the rest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<int,int> split(int x)
{
    return std::make_pair(x/10, x%10);
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> z = split(113);

    std::cout << z.first << " " << z.second;
}
```

I also used [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) to return the result.

Answer (score 2):

You want `N % 10` to get the one's digit. For the other digits `N / 10`.