# C++ Checking for valid bank checks

Tags: c++

Hey there I am working on an assignment for my programming 1 class and I am having difficulties. We have to take in user input for a check number and then check if its valid. Our professor said we need to take in the check number as a string value and then convert it into an int at first which I do not understand. here's what I have and know and an example.

```
 1  0  3  0  0  0  6  4  8     bank number
  7  3  9  7  3  9  7  3        multipliers
  7  0 27  0  0  0 42 12        products
  7  7 34 34 34 34 76 88        subtotals
  88                            sum
  8                             check digit
```

the last digit is attached to make sure modulo 10 of the sum and the last digit equal each other. I have an array with {7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3} but I am not sure how to use just a single digit of the long bank code. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you written so far and where exactly are you stuck?  Helping you will be easier if you can provide what you've written so far so we can see where you're at.

Comment: I think the only thing I need help on now is using the string value I get input into for ex. 103000648 and using the individual numbers(1,0,3,0,0,0,6,4,8) so that I can multiply them by my units in my array. So I can make a loop like for(i=0;i<inAr[].length;i++){subtotal*= intAr[i] * and then the digits of the bank code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get individual numbers from the string number do this after getting an integer value from the string

```
vector<int> digitstack;
while(number>0)
{                         
    digit = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
    digitstack.push_bac(digit);
    sum = sum+digit; 
}
```

this will help you in getting individual nubers, ina vector and then you can use them individually by looping

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < digitstack.size() ; i++ )
{
   int number  = digitstack[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int iCheckNumber = atoi( stringCheckNumber ); This will convert the string into an integer( iCheckNumber ). You can use this number as an integer there on ( a single number i mean ). please let me know if this is what you are expecting

Comment: Will this let me use individual numbers from the converted int? say i use a string 500 and make it an int can i use just the 0 digit(5) to perform arithmetic with?

Comment: I have an answer for you down beneath, but you can use your own mathemtical logic to get them individually after you have converted the string into a number ( answered above ). You can check on other logic to separate the number individually

Comment: I very much appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you mate. all the best. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207696/split-an-integer-into-its-digits-c   to get an idea of individually seperating the number